# mysql load query not working perfectly

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data into a table via load command in my sql but when ever i run my query the data is entered only in first column and the other one is null

My text file is:

```
     - 1      server
     - 2      client 
     - 3      network
     - 4      system
```

First column is error code and second is comment and query is:

```
load data local infile 'C:/Users/nco/Desktop/help.txt' into table help;
```

After that `select * from help;`

And the output is:

```
mysql> select * from help;
+------------+-------------+
| error_code | description |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 | NULL        |
|          2 | NULL        |
|          3 | NULL        |
|          4 | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the file on Windows with an editor that uses \r\n as a line terminator, you should use this statement instead:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/nco/Desktop/help.txt' INTO TABLE help
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```